# Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur

Tags: bug, status-completed, images

I am getting this message

> Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur

However upon cursory browsing

[`imgur.com`](http://imgur.com)

appears to load fine.

Comment: That's a server side message. The server tried to upload to imgur and was unable. Is this persistent?

Comment: @Oded it is persistent

Comment: Can you try again? Added some extra logging, so if the issue is still there, I can see why.

Comment: Looks like some stale DNS entries on our server - how is it now?

Comment: Same thing happening to me right now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imgur is making some changes on their side (I'm not sure what's public, so won't go into detail) in order to grow and part of that is moving the `stack.imgur.com` services over as well.  This is for a bunch of reasons, one of which being SSL support on `i.stack.imgur.com`.

This was a case of a non-resolved DNS entry being cached for API calls to imgur on a specific web server, which has been resolved.  We'll keep an eye on this but that shift shouldn't happen again any time soon.

Comment: Just don't let them break anything. :)

Comment: I just post [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313730/failed-to-upload-image) and looks like you handle it before.