# Failed to upload image

Tags: bug, uploader

Looks like there are problems on imgur

> Ironically I try to post the printscreen here

Show the following error

> Failed to upload image; an error occured at imgur

Seem to have happen before but with different message, so I report it just in case.

[Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186038/failed-to-upload-image-couldnt-reach-imgur)

[Intermittent Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291609/intermittent-failed-to-upload-image-imgur-is-rejecting-the-request)